# How to search on specific columns with TNTSearch in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout

Below is my model code `Product.php.`

```php
public $asYouType = true;

public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $array = $this->toArray();

    // Customize array...

    return $array;
}
```

Controller code

```php
$phones = Product::search($request['phone'])->get();
```

Now I want to search for products from my product table, but TNTSearch is searching all columns in my tables and gives me the result. However, I am working on an e-commerce site, and I want results by product title and then from the description column.

My table structure looks like the below image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For indexing `specific columns` you should set custom array,

For instance:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        $array =  [

            //'title'    => $this->title,
            'description' => $this->description
        ];

        return $array;
    }
```

In above example we ignore the title field content to indexing and just index `description` field.

Comment: if we want to use in 2 different condition, one in title and another one in description, how we do?